# MySQL table a global variable, ejs and nodejs

Tags: mysql, node.js, ejs

I'm trying to figure out how I can make a global variable that can grab from a mysql table.

```
app.get('*', function(req, res, next){
  res.locals.user = req.user || null;
  res.locals.mobs = db.query('SELECT * FROM mobs', function(err, rows){
    var rowLength = rows.length;
    for (var i = 0; i < rowLength; i++) {
      var mobs = rows[i];
    }
  });
```

The mobs ones is what I am trying to do. using `<%= mobs[0].name %>` produces a a cant get from undefined.

Answer (score 0):

I think you need this

```
db.query('SELECT * FROM mobs', function(err, rows){
      res.locals.mobs = rows
  });
```

if you want pass the data to template try this

```
db.query('SELECT * FROM mobs', function(err, rows){
               res.render('view.ejs',{mob:rows})
          });
```

Comment: I tried this: 
  `res.locals.mobs = db.query('SELECT * FROM mobs', function(err, rows){
    req.locals.mobs = rows;
  });` But I ended up getting a `TypeError: Cannot set property 'mobs' of undefined` I'm not sure if that means req.locals is undefined or rows is undefined. Also your first one didn't work. Dont remember the error

Comment: actually what do you want??

Comment: I want to be able to pull data from the database table using `mobs[row].column` , if it helps, the `req.locals.user = req.user` makes it so I can pull information of the logged in user.

Answer (score 0):

I found an answer! I am not sure if it is the most efficient, but here it is:

```
app.use(function(req, res, next) {
  res.locals.errors = null;
  // Mob Database
  db.query('SELECT * FROM mobs', function(err, rows){
    req.mobs = rows;
    res.locals.mobs = req.mobs;
  });
  next();
});
```